# time.now now in ruby 1.8.7 vs ruby 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, ruby-2.0, ruby-1.8.7

Currently i am upgrading my application from ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 2.
I got the following issue datetime.

Ruby 1.8.7 console:

```
u=User.find :last
 => #<User id: 1191, login: "srivaishvi@gmail.com", name: "Sri Lakshmi", email: "srivaishvi.local@gmail.com" , created_at: "2014-01-27 12:09:04", updated_at: "2014-01-28 15:57:23"> 
u.updated_at="1/13/2014"
 => "1/13/2014" 
u.save
 => true
```

Ruby 2 console:

```
u=User.find :last
 => #<User id: 1191, login: "srivaishvi@gmail.com", name: "Sri Lakshmi", email: "srivaishvi.local@gmail.com" , created_at: "2014-01-27 12:09:04", updated_at: "2014-01-28 15:57:23"> 
u.updated_at="1/13/2014"
 => "1/13/2014" 
u.save
 *****ArgumentError: argument out of range*****
```

I want the Ruby 1.8.7 datetime format in Ruby 2. I would like to keep using format I used in Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. Now I understand your requirement. In that case, you can change the default format through out the application. Please follow the steps mentioned in the link,

http://blog.nicoschuele.com/posts/cheatsheet-to-set-app-wide-date-and-time-formats-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to update a updated_at field. Record will be updated, but it will not be the date you actually wanted.

```
>> u.updated_at = "1/13/2014"
=> "1/13/2014"
>> u.save
=> true
>> u.updated_at
=> Wed, 29 Jan 2014 18:12:51 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: This is juz an example how its differ from ruby 1.8.7.
whereever we use date filed in in ruby 1.8.7
(1/13/2014 it will save as jan 13 but in ruby 2 its taking 13 as a month.thats why its throwing out of range.(istead of 1/13/2014 if i give 13/1/2014 it will take.))

Comment: ruby 2 expecting in dd/mm/yy format.but in existing its coming as mm/dd/yy